# How to extend <tr> CSS to 2 rows at a time?

Tags: php, html, css

I found and adapted this CSS:

```
tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #fffaf0;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem;
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 2px #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

My goal was to use `rowspan = "2"` to make an image display on a left margin and have info on the right side, sort of like a card layout, but it is coming out in 2 separate "cards".

```
echo "<table class='center'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<tr><td rowspan="2">';
        if ($row['webLink'] != NULL){
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$row['webLink'].'"><img class="contain" height="300" width="300" src="'.$row['img'].'" /></a>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<img class="contain" height="300" width="300" src="'.$row['img'].'" />';
        }
        echo '</td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr><tr><td>';
        if ($row['addy'] != NULL){
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$row['addyLink'].'">'.$row['addy'].'</a>';
        }
        
        echo '</td><td></td></tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

[What I'm aiming for vs what I'm getting img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svioy.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing for CSS. But it seems to me that you dont fill the table with tabular data and as such proberly better off by using Flexbox or CSS-Grid. Tables should be soley used for tabular data with expetion of e-mail templates.

Comment: Don't use table layouts.

Comment: @tacoshy how would I order flex box in the grid format? I've attempted `flex-direction` and grouping and nesting divs and its not working. Rather it's not moving how I want it to

Comment: I know you have added an image already. Can you please use a more clear and specific drawing of the exact intended layout. The more details, the better.